# Devise: Don't display "unauthenticated" flash message when redirected to users/sign_in from root path

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Using Devise 2.2.4 in Rails 3.2.

When not logged in, and I go to the url myapp.com/documents, Devise redirects me to myapp.com/users/sign_in and displays the flash message configured in devise.en.yml under devise.failure.unauthenticated.

This is desirable!

When not logged in, and I go to the url myapp.com (the root path), Devise redirects similarly and displays the same flash message.

The redirection is still desirable, the flash message not so much.

Is there a way to configure Devise to NOT display the flash 'unauthenticated' message if redirecting from the root path?  I know I can get around it in a custom FailureApp, but this would seem to be a common enough case that a simpler resolution should exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may replace `before_filter :authenticate_user!` or something you use with your own code which will not set the message.

Answer (score 11):

You can remove the flash message in your SessionsController after the redirect.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_filter :remove_authentication_flash_message_if_root_url_requested

  private

  def remove_authentication_flash_message_if_root_url_requested
    if session[:user_return_to] == root_path and flash[:alert] == I18n.t('devise.failure.unauthenticated')
      flash[:alert] = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: flash.delete(:alert) if session[:user_return_to] == root_path && flash[:alert] == I18n.t('devise.failure.unauthenticated')

Answer (score 4):

I simply went to `devise.en.yml` and removed the `unauthenticated` message, leaving it as:

```
unauthenticated: ""
```

Answer (score 1):

[I don't think a simpler solution exists](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/2aedb1bf795947f189183fbd1e479719463f6395/lib/devise/failure_app.rb#L56-L65). You can do it like Speransky Danil said or you can use a custom FailureApp. It's not that complicated, but it is brittle since you'll have to override a method that calls other methods that could be changed in future versions of Devise:

```
# app/config/initializers/devise.rb
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect
    store_location!
    if flash[:timedout] && flash[:alert]
      flash.keep(:timedout)
      flash.keep(:alert)
    elsif attempted_path != root_path
      flash[:alert] = i18n_message 
    end
    redirect_to redirect_url
  end
end

Devise.setup do |config|
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
end
```

So I'd go for Speransky Danil suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the real problem has turned out to be application-specific.  The root path is routed to a controller that subverts Devise's behavior and performs its own redirects based on custom circumstances if a user is not signed in.  It's THESE redirects that Devise is trapping and correctly handling based on the information it has.

Thanks for the input.  I'm going to mark Speransky's comment as the answer, since technically that's what we're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me

```rb
# app/lib/custom_failure_app.rb
class CustomFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def route(scope)
    flash.clear
    super
  end
end
```

```rb
# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailureApp
  end
end
```